# How to use array headers in cURL?

Tags: php, arrays, header

I want to create a "Proxy" in PHP. I'm working on Header Forwarding (Get client headers and use them in the request) using curl.

I have created an array like this:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Authorization: token',
);
```

It returns a good array and it working with curl

```
Array
(
    [0] => Content-type: application/xml
    [1] => Authorization: token
)
```

But when I get client headers (using the get all headers() function) it returns a different array and it is not working with curl.

```
Array
(
    [Authorization] => token
    [Content-Type] => application/json
)
```

Any solution?

Comment: you should convert input header in form your app desired

Comment: curl wants headers in HTTP key/value mode, PHP is simplifying your live by give you an array which HTTP doesn't support. See the [first example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php#example-4673) for converting it back.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

You could get it back to normal by doing:

```
$newHeaderList = array();
foreach(getallheaders() as $key => $value){
  array_push($newHeaderList, "{$key}:{$value}");
}
print_r($newHeaderList);
```